# MacOS Locking Down DNS Settings

Tags: macos, mac, dns, default-settings, lock

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to lock the DNS settings on a Macbook (Settings > Networks > Advanced > DNS)? I want to set DNS settings and not be able to access them afterward. I was able to do it on my windows laptop but recently got a macbook. Please help!

Comment: To what end? If you have an admin account you can undo anything you do anyway.

Comment: The only way I know to do this is to run as a standard user (i.e. not an administrator). But if you know the admin account's password, you can just use that to unlock it even then...

Comment: I was after a way where it would not lock other settings as well